# Selecting proper amplifier output level

Tags: amplifier

I am powering 6 CVS 8 Tannoy Ceiling speakers: https://www.tannoy.com/Categories/Tannoy/CVS/CVS-8/p/P0BSK

The specifications say they have a 60W continuous operating power and a 240 Watt peak power. I am powering all 6 speakers on one channel of one amp that has a maximum power output of 1000W. (It is an 8 channel 8000W amp. 1000 W per channel).

Is it ok to turn up the level to maximum on that amp channel because it will be under the total peak wattage of `240 * 6 = 1440W` or is it dangerous as that will be over the total continuous wattage `60 * 6 = 360W`.

Obviously I am a beginner here, but have been thrown into a situation with many speakers and amps. All help/comments appreciated.

Comment: How are you planning to connect them to the amp? Series? Parallel? Probably you'll need a combination of the 2. There's two things you need to match when connecting multiple speakers to single amp channels - Power and impedance. I'm afraid it's a little more complicated than you may think. Luckily there's plenty of resources on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

On the link provided it clearly states that these speakers have "traps" for 70V or 100V installations. This would mean that a specific 70V or 100V constant voltage amplifier would be needed.

Please search for "how to wire amplifier for installation 100V" and you will get plenty of resources. [Example](https://geoffthegreygeek.com/understanding-distributed-speaker-systems/) (This is just a brief explanation of 100V system, it does get more complex when designing a full system)

However this is probably not something you want to do without having the proper experience. **100V or 70V constant voltage is lethal.**

To be complete: There is a reference to "6 Ohm direct input" and the [Operating Manual](https://www.tannoy.com/Categories/Tannoy/CVS/CVS-8/p/P0BSK/Downloads) suggests a maximum Amplifier of 120 W @ 6 Ohm.

However as these are ceiling speakers, possibly with long feedlines which affect the total impedance of the load to the amplifier, I would not, and cannot advise you to use this suggested/unspecified amplifier.

Furthermore you need to check the relevant Electrical Code. Depending on where you are in the world there might be requirements in regards to the wiring of 100V or 70V speaker system in regards to conduit to be used for cable runs.

Best advise here is **not** to use the amplifier you are suggesting without further specification, and involve product support of the speaker and/or a reputable installer for this.